# What is the time complexity of inserting n elements to the end of an array?

Tags: c, data-structures

i know that inserting an element to an array takes a constant time let us say c.

What I have tried:

for inserting n element
     `time=c+c+c+.......n times =nc`

i want to ask that will it be big O of n or o(1).

Comment: So the time is `nc` as you calculated. So what is the complexity then?

Comment: Each adding to the array is O(1), but you're doing it n times, which means it all in all have to be O(n) (for a standard "array" that have a fixed size, and you're not reallocating it dynamically).

Comment: The speed of inserting items into an array depends on things like data cache, data size, parallelism options, available CPU registers etc etc. It does not depend on some theoretical "big O" nonsense from the 1960s. Focus on real-world computers instead of fictional "computer science computers". "Big O" theory has been dead for some 30 years.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, adding `n` elements requires O(n) time, but adding an individual item is not O(1). It's *amortized* O(1).

Any given add may require O(n) time by itself because the current array's space has been filled, so it must be copied to another, larger space.

But if the new space allocation is a *constant factor greater than one* of the original (2 is often used), then the copy costs amortize so that average time per add is constant as you say, and `n` adds are O(n).

To make this clearer, consider the case where the factor is 2 and initial array size is 1. Then consider copy costs to grow the array from size 1 to where it's large enough to hold, 2^k+1 elements for any k>=0. This size is 2^(k+1). Total copy costs will include all the copying to become that big in factor-of-2 steps:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k = 2^(k+1) - 1 = 2n - 1
```

The equalities are due to basic algebra. The result is O(n). However, the last copy itself has n = 2^k elements, which is also O(n).

Comment: This answer is too good for the question :)   It needs to be somewhere on SO, but not here.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a linked list, which requires traversing the list to add to the end, arrays have constant time access to any array member.

So assuming the array doesn't need to be resized, adding an element to the end is O(1), meaning that adding n elements is O(n).

Comment: In Linked list if you are keep tracking of last added node so it will be same O(n) for linked list as well means you are maintaining tail pointer