# python array time complexity?

Tags: python, numpy

What's the `.append` time complexity of `array.array` and `np.array` ?

I see time complexity for `list`, `collections.deque`, `set`, and `dict` in [python_wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) , but I can't find the time complexity of `array.array` and `np.array`. Where can I find them?

Comment: Do you mean `array.array`? For numpy, it's definitely linear

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes~

Comment: `np.append()` is fairly slow, it will involve copying the entire array

Comment: List append append is relatively efficient, since it just adds a reference to the object to the 'expansion' space of the list.  `np.append` is a poorly conceived cover function for `np.concatenate`.  It makes a whole new array each time.  Best practice is to list append in a loop, and do just one concatenate at the end to make an array.

Comment: `array.array` and `numpy.ndarray` are entirely different implementations.  One can grow, in much the same way as `list`.  The other cannot.  `ndarray` is designed primarily for efficient multidimensional calculations.  Last year I answered a similar question - [Is there a list of big O complexities for the numpy library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201990/is-there-a-list-of-big-o-complexities-for-the-numpy-library)

Answer (score 2):

So to link you provided *(also a **TLDR**)* `list` are internally "represented as an array" <sub>[link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list)</sub> It's supposed to be O(1) with a note at the bottom saying:

> "These operations rely on the "Amortized" part of "Amortized Worst Case". Individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container."
>   <sub>[link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#Notes)</sub>

---

**More details**

It doesn't go into detail in the docs but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/arraymodule.c) you'll actually see what's going on. Python `array`s have internal buffer(s) that allow for quick resizing of themselves and will `realloc` as it grows/shrinks.

`array.append` uses [`arraymodule.array_array_append`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f8cebd32c1e6f20a1a1440e51c308a5f70ca959/Modules/arraymodule.c#L1317) which calls [`arraymodule.ins`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f8cebd32c1e6f20a1a1440e51c308a5f70ca959/Modules/arraymodule.c#L1071) calling [`arraymodule.ins1`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f8cebd32c1e6f20a1a1440e51c308a5f70ca959/Modules/arraymodule.c#L622) which is the meat and potatoes of the operation. Incidentally `array.extend` uses this as well but it just supplies it `Py_SIZE(self)` as the insertion index.

So if we read the notes in `arraymodule.ins1` it starts off with:

> ```
> Bypass realloc() when a previous overallocation is large enough
> to accommodate the newsize.  If the newsize is 16 smaller than the
> current size, then proceed with the realloc() to shrink the array.
> ```
>
> <sup>[link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f8cebd32c1e6f20a1a1440e51c308a5f70ca959/Modules/arraymodule.c#L123)</sup>
>
> ...
>
> ```
> This over-allocates proportional to the array size, making room
> for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
> enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
> sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
> system realloc().
> The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 34, 46, 56, 67, 79, ...
> Note, the pattern starts out the same as for lists but then
> grows at a smaller rate so that larger arrays only overallocate
> by about 1/16th -- this is done because arrays are presumed to be more
> memory critical.
> ```
>
> <sup>[link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f8cebd32c1e6f20a1a1440e51c308a5f70ca959/Modules/arraymodule.c#L143)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

It is important to understand the `array` data structure to answer your question. Since both `array` objects are based on C arrays ([regular](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.append), [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy)), they share a lot of the same functionality.

Adding  an item to an array is *amortized* `O(1)`, but in most cases, ends up being `O(n)` time. This is because it could be the case that your array object is not filled yet, and thus appending some data to that spot in memory is a relatively trivial exercise, it is `O(1)`. However, in most cases, the array is full and thus needs to be completely copied over in memory with the new item added to it. This is a very expensive operation since an array of `n` size needs to be copied, thus making the insertion `O(n)`.

[An interesting example from this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175867/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-inserting-n-elements-to-the-end-of-an-array)

> To make this clearer, consider the case where the factor is `2` and
>   initial array size is `1`. Then consider copy costs to grow the array
>   from size 1 to where it's large enough to hold, 2^k+1 elements for any
>   `k >= 0`. This size is `2^(k+1)`. Total copy costs will include all the
>   copying to become that big in factor-of-2 steps:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k = 2^(k+1) - 1 = 2n - 1
```

Comment: `not filled yet` does not apply to a `numpy` array.  Its size is fixed.  You may set element values, but you can't grow it.  You can only make a new array and copy old and new values to it (or let `np.concatenate` do it for you).

Comment: The size can be allocated, but it can be the case that the object in memory does not have a reference yet.